# ImportError: When Trying to Import Custom File - Django JWT

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm using **django-rest-framework-jwt** to generate a token for security, but I need to get the user information with the token when someone logs in. The only way I have seen to do this is to create a custom function that will override the default functionality. I'm very new to Django so I'm still trying to figure out how things work, this is what I have tried after reading [THIS](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/145#issuecomment-249349031) article. I have tried MANY ways to get this working, but this seems like the best approach.

Problem I have when I use the current setup I get:

> ImportError: Could not import 'custom_jwt.jwt_response_payload_handler' for API setting 'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER'. ImportError: No module named custom_jwt.

1 - after creating the `custom_jwt.py` what is best practices on where to put it? If there is none, any suggestions on where?

2- how would I gain access to the functions in `custom_jwt.py` in the `settings.py`?

## settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'custom_jwt.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'custom_jwt.jwt_payload_handler',
}
```

## custom_jwt.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


def jwt_payload_handler(user):
    """
    Custom payload handler 
    Token encrypts the dictionary returned by this function, and can be decoded by rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler
    """
    return {
        'user_id': user.pk,
        'email': user.email,
        'is_superuser': user.is_superuser,
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + api_settings.JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA,
        'orig_iat': timegm(
            datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple()
        )
    }


def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    """ 
    Custom response payload handler.
    This function controlls the custom payload after login or token refresh. This data is returned through the web API.
    """
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': {
             'email': user.email,
        }
    }
```

## project structure

```
project
    account
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        managers.py
        models.py
        serializers.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    core
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        custom_jwt.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        db.sqlite3
```

## Python Version

```
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: What python version?

Comment: Forgot to include that - Python 2.7.10

Comment: I looked at site-packages > rest_framework_jwt > utils.py to see how I might it working. I noticed I may have had my `custom_jwt.py` in the wrong app, so I moved it to `account` and changed the `settings.py` and it worked... some what. One I get it working I'll post what I did for future peeps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving my file to `account` which at that point resided in a app(module). From looking at `site-packages > rest_framework_jwt > utils.py` I learned they called their file `utils.py` which I feel is more of a standard, so I renamed the `custom_jwt.py` to `utils.py`.

## settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    """
    I found I did not need to change JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    """
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'account.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
}
```

## utils.py

```
# I created a custom User so I need to import the serializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer


def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    """
    Custom response payload handler.
    This function controls the custom payload after login or token refresh. This data is returned through the web API.
    """

    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
    }
```

## Desired Response

```
{"token":"....", "user":{"id":1, "email": "test@testing.com", "first": "test", "last": "guy"}}
```